# Python | Extending a list by a certain number (given parameters)

Tags: python

Suppose I have a function with three parameters:

example(mid, a, b)

I want to return a list of integers that counts from mid, a numbers lower and b numbers higher.

For instance,
if I had example(10, 5, 2), it would give me [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12] or
if I had example(3, 7, 5), it would give me [-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].

I only started with

`def example(mid, a, b):`

How would I go about doing this? I'm a real beginner at Python so explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: all you have to do is, create a start and end range based on inputs and then create a list using those values using forloop

Comment: `list(range(mid-a, mid + b + 1))` you don't need the list you can iterate over the range() itself if needed.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an implementation of said function:

```py
def mid_counter(mid, a, b):
    return [i for i in range(mid-a, mid+b+1)]
```

The i for i in range() loop is appending each i of the iteration to the array. We want our range to be from mid-a to mid+b+1 so that is our start and end range.